# Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, marshalling

I have the following autogenerated classes from xsd.

```
<xs:element name="Add" type="tns:AddType"/>

<xs:complexType name="AddCatalogDataItem">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="tns:AddType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="tns:Code"/>
                <xs:element ref="tns:Value" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="LoadDataRequest">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="AppDataType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="tns:Code"/>
                <xs:element ref="tns:RegCode" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="tns:Add" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

While creating an request during marshalling stage i'm getting this error:

Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class com.ats.vis.services.concentrator.AddCatalogDataItem nor any of its super class is known to this context.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "LoadDataRequest")
public class LoadDataRequest
    extends AppDataType {}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AddType", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
@XmlSeeAlso({
     AddCatalogDataItem.class,
    AddCatalogDataResult.class
})
public class AddType {}
```

Here is the piece of code of creation.

```
LoadDataRequest appdt = new LoadDataRequest();
AddCatalogDataItem add = new AddCatalogDataItem();              
add.getAny().add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(NS_CONC, "Code"),String.class, updateOper.code));
аppdt.getAny().add(add);
```

And code of marshaller.

```
private SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(LoadDataRequest request) throws SOAPException, JAXBException {
    SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
    Marshaller marshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(request.getClass()).createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    JAXBElement<LoadDataRequest> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<>(new QName(NS_CONC, "LoadDataRequest"), LoadDataRequest.class, request);

    marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, message.getSOAPBody());

    return message;
}
```

I'm running out of ideas what is wrong with this code. Please, help.

Comment: Why do you are using `JAXBElement<LoadDataRequest>` ? try to call marshaller using `request` object.

Comment: @Xstian Still no luck

Comment: Add `@XmlRootElement` on your classes. Should works fine in this way. Sorry I didn't see before.

Comment: @Xstian I've updated the description (xsd part). Still no luck. @ XmlRootElement didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by creating jaxb context using following method:

```
JAXBContext jaxb = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.ats.vis.services.concentrator", com.ats.vis.services.concentrator.LoadDataRequest.class.getClassLoader());
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxb.createMarshaller();
```